# Are מתיהדים (geirim) required to give precedence to Yisra'Elim today?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, am-yisrael-jewish-nation, kavod

Are מתיהדים also known as geirim or proselytes, the descendants of converts to the Israelite religion, required to give precedence to Yisra'Elim today?

https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/12335-precedence

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_precedence

What about when Moshiach arrives?

Comment: Gerim are generally considered to be converts themselves, for almost all purposes mentioned in your article their children already count as "Israelites".

Comment: Please clarify (in the question!) what you mean by "required to give precedence". Precedence is not (usually?) owned by an individual, for him to give. It is something the community/congregation/group gives to him. For instance, an _Isra'eli_ doesn't own precedence in going up to the first [reading from the Torah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliyah_(Torah)), so that he is required to give it to a _Kohen_. It is the congregation (through the [Gabbai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabbai)) that gives the _Kohen_ the precedence.